# How can I build a sln with mixed frameworks

Tags: c#, .net, docker, .net-core

I have a solution file containing projects targeting mixed frameworks:

- MySolution.sln

  - MySolution.Library.csproj
  - MySolution.Library.Tests.csproj
  - (Some more libraries and test projects)

All non-test projects target .NET Standard 2.0 set up like:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

and all test projects target both .NET Framework 4.7.2 and .NET Core 3.1:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net472;netcoreapp3.1</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

We have a Dockerfile that builds the solution (via `dotnet build MySolution.sln`) into an image. However this is run on Linux so obviously we want to only build against .NET Core 3.1 as .NET Framework is not applicable on Linux.

I have tried:

- `dotnet build -f netcoreapp3.1 MySolution.sln` (doesn't work because the library projects do not target .NET Core 3.1)
- `dotnet build -f netstandard2.0 MySolution.sln` (does not work because the test projects do not target .NET Standard 2.0)

> error NETSDK1005: Assets file '/blah/project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'netstandard2.0' in the TargetFrameworks for your project.

What can I do make it build on Linux?

Comment: why dont you compile them seperately?

Comment: The default docker support within visual studio will add one `Dockerfile` per project where the script calls `dotnet build "MyProject.csproj"`. If you want all to build together, you can make a `docker-compose` file and call `docker-compose build` on that.

Comment: That's an option but I want to know if there is a simpler way without having to build twice.